# Как передать List из Java в JNI (C++) по сслыке?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, jni

у меня есть функция написаная на C++(JNI) которая получает как параметр `jobject` (это по сути мой List) и заполняет его данными.

Я могу вызвать эту функцию из `Java` передать ей `List<Integer>` и она действительно заполнит его(в моем случае семерками).

Но проблема в том, что функция создает свою область с памяти и заполняет ее... В итоге мой `List` остается не заполненым...

То, что мне нужно сделать это как то передать `List` из `Java` по сслыке... Чтоб код из `JNI` работал уже с тем, что я ему передал, а не создавал свое...

Вот такой код

С++

В `MyClass` метод

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_google_ar_core_examples_java_helloar_HelloArActivity_fillList(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */,
    jobject input
) {
jclass alCls = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");

if (alCls == nullptr ) {
    return;
}

jmethodID alGetId  = env->GetMethodID(alCls, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jmethodID alSizeId = env->GetMethodID(alCls, "size", "()I");

if (alGetId == nullptr || alSizeId == nullptr) {
    env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls);
    return;
}

int pointCount = static_cast<int>(env->CallIntMethod(input, alSizeId));

if (pointCount < 1) {
    env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls);
    return;
}

std::vector<int> points;
points.reserve(pointCount);

for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; ++i) {
    points.push_back(7);
}

env->DeleteLocalRef(alCls);
}
```

Вот написано в `Java`

```
public native void fillList(List<Integer> input);

private void TEST_DELETE_IT()
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    {
        {
            add(1);
            add(1);
            add(1);
            add(1);
        }
    };

    fillList(list);

    Log.e("TAG", "Here I expect to get my List full with 7");
}
```

Как передать `List` из `Java` в `JNI` по сслыке?

**ПРАВКА**

Может вообще следует передавать не `List` а `array`? Мне кажется это должно быть проще...

**ПРАВКА**

Добавил вызов метода `get` теперь функция выглядит вот так

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_google_ar_core_examples_java_helloar_HelloArActivity_fillList(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */,
    jobject input
) {

jclass java_util_ArrayList = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");

if (java_util_ArrayList == nullptr) {
    return;
}

jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_ = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "<init>", "(I)V");
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_get = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_add = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_size = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "size", "()I");

if (java_util_ArrayList_add == nullptr || java_util_ArrayList_get == nullptr || java_util_ArrayList_size == nullptr) {
    env->DeleteLocalRef(java_util_ArrayList);
    return;
}

int pointCount = static_cast<int>(env->CallIntMethod(input, java_util_ArrayList_size));

if (pointCount < 1) {
    env->DeleteLocalRef(java_util_ArrayList);
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; ++i) {
    env->CallBooleanMethod(input, java_util_ArrayList_add, 7);
}

env->DeleteLocalRef(java_util_ArrayList);
```

}

И действительно теперь это работает правильно - я передаю `List` с 4мя элементами, вызываю функцию которая добавляет мне в `List` еще 4 элемента. Но только проблема в том, что она добавляет не `Integer`, а какой то обьект типа `DexCache` , что это ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы 7-ки добавляете не в переданный `ArrayList`. С чего бы им в нём появится?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а вы прочитали 3й абзац сверху в моем вопросе? От сюда и возник сам вопрос, "Как передать List по сслыке" ? чтоб заполнять именно то что мне нужно, а не созданный внутри функции

Comment: В аргументе `input` и есть ссылка на список. Но вы её используете только для вызова метода `size`. Вместо того, чтобы вызываеть метод `add` переданного списка, вы зачем-то создаёте локальный вектор и добавляете данные в него.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, но `input` имеет тип `jobject` как его можно прикастить к `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: К `std::vector<int>` его прикастить нельзя. Да и не нужно. Если нужно добавить в `ArrayList` элемент, то получайте ссылку на метод `add`, аналогично тому, как получали на `size`, и вызывайте этот метод, передавая ему параметром данные, которые должны быть добавлены в список.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а понял. Ок. Добавил правку в вопрос. Почему то он добавляет обьекты типа `DexCache` , а не `Integer` , есть предположения почему?

Comment: Не знаю, с NDK не доводилось работать. Попробуйте в нативном коде создавать объекты Integer и добавлять их в список.